# Command Line Printing - Adobe Reader and GhostScript

Tags: reporting-services, command-line, printing, adobe, ghostscript

I am trying to use command line printing for some of my reports created using SSRS to a network printer.

Not able to get any successful results, after some testing on Windows command prompt. Without any error message given, I have no idea whether I am heading the right way or not.

**Using Adobe Reader**

Not working

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" /t "e:\temp\1.pdf" \\printserver\myprinter
```

but when I try to use Adobe, open the file and print manually, it works.

**Using GhostScript**

Not working

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin\gswin64.exe" -dPrinted -dBatch -sOutputFile="\\\printserver\myprinter" "e:\temp\1.pdf"
```

Do I need to install network printer driver on my server ? or my command line is incorrect ?

Thanks ...

Comment: Ghostscript **requires** a device to be selected and you haven't chosen one so you get the default, probably the display device. You need to add -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 to your command line. In addition note that this device uses the Windows printer pipeline in order to create whatever the printer requires as input. This means that you must have the printer driver installed locally on the computer and the printer must be available locally as well. That is, you must be able to print to that printer from the computer in question, though the physical printer can be on a print server..

Comment: Thanks KenS, I am going to try adding the printer on my server and try again. The reason why I didn't install a printer is because I seen my other server manage to send the document directly to the printer without adding a printer. I thought it is the same case...